# Jquery Date Format with DateTime

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want show a date in a textbox, this date is an attribute from an object of type `DateTime`.

I'm using :

```
$("input[id*='_txtFechaIngresado']").val(denunciaCentralizada.FechaDeIngreso);
```

But the result is /DATE/(92837294387)/ and i want show you for example `30/12/2015`.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: denunciaCentralizada is an object and FechaDeIngreso your attribute

Comment: When you set the value and how to `FechaDeIngreso`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
var formattedDate = new Date("yourUnformattedDate");
var d = formattedDate.getDate();
var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
$("input[id*='_txtFechaIngresado']").val(d + "." + m + "." + y);
```